# Dynamic Dimension Security

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2012, ssas, dimension

I have a cube in SSAS 2012 with about 30 dimensions, one of which is `Company`.

The `Company` dimension contains a list of companies, of which there are several hundred in the cube.  Our security model requires that users have visibility only to those `Company` values to which they have been assigned.

In our SQL Server environment, we control this access through a series of functions that are `JOIN`ed in `VIEW`s.  The functions return a table listing all the `Company` values, which is used to filter results.

For instance:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.FakeView
AS
SELECT d.*
FROM FunctionToGetAccess(SYSTEM_USER) f
INNER JOIN DataTable d
    ON d.CompanyID = f.CompanyID
```

**Is there a way for me to port this logic, or a similar logic, to dimension-level security in SSAS?**

A couple of notes:

- The Cube will be rebuilt overnight
- Security does not have to be current hourly, but should be reprocessed during the cube processing overnight
- I would strongly prefer not to have to materialize the list of users and allowed clients into a table or dimension

Answer (score 3):

You need to overcome your scruples and materialize the list of users and allowed clients into a dimension, then apply security to that dimension.  If you have Enterprise Edition you can hide the dimension from the users.